# How to convert entity to message with @classmethod

Tags: python, google-app-engine, protorpc

I have this model:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    firstname = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    lastname = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    email = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    birthday = ndb.DateProperty(required = True)

    @classmethod
    def to_message(self):
        return UserMessage(firstname = self.firstname,
                           lastname = self.lastname,
                           email = self.email,
                           birthday_day = self.birthday.day)
```

Where UserMessage is a protoRPC object. And want something like this:

```
user = User.query(User.email == 'john@example.com').get()
user_message = user.to_message()
```

Comment: Weird, what is the value of birthday? I just tested (with db.DateProperty though, assuming they're same) and it works fine

Comment: That's the point, they aren't. I'm migrating from db to ndb and this happened :/

Comment: Actually, the problem is not with the ndb. I will update the question..

Comment: You can;t use a class method here.  There is no self, by convention it is cls and you are passed the class not an instance.  to_message should be a normal method.

Comment: As answered, convert it to a property rather that classmethod, in order to use self

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a class method here.

There is no `self` in a classmethod , by convention it is `cls` and you are passed the class not an instance. `to_message` should be a normal method.